# How to store credentials and password in for dev and production (Azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

How should i store my credentials/password/api_keys for development and production app. At the moment, i put all the sensitive information in public consts class? My production app will be in azure. What is the best practice? Can anyone give me suggestions or point me to an article that i can follow?

Answer (score 1):

We could set it in the Azure [Website appsetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure).There is a tutorials about [How Application Strings and Connection Strings Work](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/)

> Developers can store plain vanilla key-value pairs as well as key-value pairs that will be used as connection strings. Since the key-value pairs are stored behind the scenes in the Windows Azure Web Sites configuration store, the key-value pairs don’t need to be stored in the file content of your web application From a security perspective that is a nice side benefit since sensitive information such as Sql connection strings with passwords never show up as cleartext in a web.config or php.ini file.

Comment: So i put everything in webconfig. And when i upload to azure, it will be overidden by the values in azure appsettings?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If it is configurated in the azure appsettings, it will override the webconfig value.